# qsort doesn't work for float types in my impl. what is wrong?

Tags: c++, qsort

I don't know why the code doesn't work for float types, i mean the qsort algo. I tried different ways to sort it, but without success. In case of int type, the code works fine but not for floating type, It's confusing for me. Anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks for tpps.

header:

```
template <class T>
class arraysort
{
    public:

    arraysort(int);
    ~arraysort();
    //int compare (const void *a,const void *b);
    T& operator[] (int index);
    void quicksort(T a, T b);
    void printout(); 

    private:
    T *ptr;
    int size;
    const void *a;
    const void *b;
    static T compare (const void * a, const void * b);
};
```

c++

```
#include "arraysort.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
arraysort<T>::arraysort(int s)
{
    size = s;
    ptr = new T[size];
}

template <typename T>
arraysort<T>::~arraysort()
{
    delete [] ptr;
}

template <typename T>
T& arraysort<T>::operator[](int index)
{
    return ptr[index];
}

template <typename T>
T arraysort<T>:: compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    T fa = * (const T * ) a;
    T fb = * (const T * ) b;
    return (fb - fa);
}

template <typename T>
void arraysort<T>::quicksort (T a, T b)
{
  qsort(ptr, size, sizeof(T), (int( * )(const void * ,const void * )) compare);
}

template <typename T>
void arraysort<T>::printout()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout<< ptr[i] <<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `qsort` in C++, where we have `std::sort` with much better interface?

Comment: You forgot to show how you attempted to use it and what compile errors you got.

Comment: Just use `std::sort` already..

Comment: This can also have problems because [templates should be defined in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison function called by `qsort` is expected to return an `int`, but when your template uses `float` the function return a `float`.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the `compare` function to always return an `int` and perform explicit comparisons to determine which is greater.

```
template <typename T>
int arraysort<T>:: compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    T fa = * (const T * ) a;
    T fb = * (const T * ) b;

    if (fa > fb) {
        return -1;
    } else if  (fa < fb) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't handle NaN values.  You would need to figure out how to handle them separately.

Comment: I think the fa>fb case should return 1, not -1